# Power-BI Pivot Row Subtotals are getting wrong

Tags: powerbi, pivot, dax, powerquery

We have a manual calculated column called `MovedMedia/OoSEvent` which simply should be the result of `Moved Media` divided by `OoS Events`:

**(should be `MovedMedia` if `OoSEvents`== 0)*

[image]

Per row level the calculations are all fine but the aggregated subtotals are wrong as they are just sumed up per column. As shown in the picture 28.712/3 is clearly not 3.475.

Has someone any idea? Can the subtotals be calculated by my own somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a measure to first aggregate the MovedMedia and the OoS Events before performing the division, instead of a calculated column, for instance like this one

```
MovedMedia/OoSEvent =
VAR Numerator =
    SUM ( Table[MovedMedia] )
VAR Denominator =
    SUM ( Table[OoS Events] )
VAR Result =
    DIVIDE (
        Numerator,
        Denominator,
        Numerator
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

The third parameter of DIVIDE is the value to be returned when the denominator is zero